# Detecting characters having a similar connotation as in ASCII set

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, encoding, ascii

To detect if the string is composed of ASCII characters, I am using a regex that looks as follows:

```
"string".match(/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/gm)
```

This works fine in detecting the ASCII characters. But for this leaves the characters that are similar in meaning to ascii codes. For example a double quote that falls out of ASCII set and is included in unicode set. For example:

```
"see the difference in double quotes“
```

With the above regex, this string will fail the detection test because of `“`. How could I extend the above regex to include characters such as these that are very similar to meaning in ASCII set. For example, `,` [comma], `"`[double quote], etc.

Comment: What is the actual requirement and what is the pattern you tried to create to solve that issue? What is your  *issue*?

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't understand the ***meaning*** of anything, it only follows its rules to match the sequence of ***characters***.

If you want to match a comma, you need to put a comma in your character set.  If you are looking for "similar" characters, you need to identify each and every one of them and put them inside the character set.

```
[,"]
```

will match "comma" and "double quote".